# Using android.support.v7.app.ActionBar without extending ActionBarActivity

Tags: android, android-actionbar

I am trying to use the support 7 action bar. However my main activity is already extending FragmentActivity. Is there anyway of using the ActionBar without extending ActionBarActivity ?

For example : without extending this class, one cannot do :

```
ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
```

As described in http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html

Update:

As pointed out ActionBarActivity Extends FragmentActivity

Comment: `ActionBarActivity` itself [extends `FragmentActivity`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/app/ActionBarActivity.html). Hence, there should be no particular reason why you cannot have your activity extend `ActionBarActivity`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ActionBarActivity extends FragmentActivity so your app will work as it does now and additionally will have the support for actionbar. 
See class hierarchy here: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/app/ActionBarActivity.html

Comment: I removed the standard `ActionBar` import, replaced it with the support7 version. `getActionBar()` returns a type mismatch and `getSupportActionBar()` is undefined for the the type

Comment: ok got it now ... forgot to extend the correct class .. thanks

Comment: Thank you. This solves an issue in the book Android programming: The Big Nerd Ranch guide at the beginning of ch. 16.